# CatmullRomSpline does not accept type arguement

Tags: eclipse, libgdx, curve, spline, catmull-rom-curve

I am looking to create smooth paths for my 2D game. Looking at `CatmullRomSpline` it is just the thing i need. Every post, even here on `SE` is giving it a type and passing all the control points and a `Boolean` with the constructor. This seems to be obsolete now, `CatmullRomSpline` does not accept any type parameters anymore and without it it can only work with `V3` paths. Neither does the constructor accept a list of control points.

```
    cp = new Vector2[]
    {
        new Vector2(0,100), new Vector2(100,600), new Vector2(300,300), new Vector2(600, 400)
    };          
    CatmullRomSpline<Vector2> path = new CatmullRomSpline<Vector2>(cp, true);
```

This gives the following error: `The type CatmullRomSpline is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Vector2>`.

[image]

Am i missing something or does CatmullRomSpline work differently nowadays, and how?

This is the CatmullRomSpline Class from badlogic. It surely looks like things changed, i am getting this class from "import com.badlogic.gdx.math.CatmullRomSpline;"

> public class CatmullRomSpline implements Serializable {   private
>   static final long serialVersionUID = -3290464799289771451L;   private
>   List controlPoints = new ArrayList();   Vector3 T1 =
>   new Vector3();    Vector3 T2 = new Vector3();
>
> /** Adds a new control point     *       * @param point the point */
>     public void add (Vector3 point) {       controlPoints.add(point);   }
>
> /** @return all control points */   public List
>   getControlPoints () {         return controlPoints;   }
>
> /** Returns a path, between every two control points numPoints are
>   generated and the control points themselves are added too.     * The
>   first and the last controlpoint are omitted. if there's less than 4
>   controlpoints an empty path is returned.   *       * @param numPoints
>   number of points returned for a segment    * @return the path */
>     public List getPath (int numPoints) {      ArrayList
>   points = new ArrayList();
>
> ```
>   if (controlPoints.size() < 4) return points;
>
>   Vector3 T1 = new Vector3();         Vector3 T2 = new Vector3();
>
>   for (int i = 1; i <= controlPoints.size() - 3; i++) {
>       points.add(controlPoints.get(i));           float increment = 1.0f /
> ```
>
> (numPoints + 1);          float t = increment;
>
> ```
>       T1.set(controlPoints.get(i + 1)).sub(controlPoints.get(i -
> ```
>
> 1)).mul(0.5f);            T2.set(controlPoints.get(i +
>   2)).sub(controlPoints.get(i)).mul(0.5f);
>
> ```
>       for (int j = 0; j < numPoints; j++) {
>           float h1 = 2 * t * t * t - 3 * t * t + 1; // calculate basis
>           // function 1
>           float h2 = -2 * t * t * t + 3 * t * t; // calculate basis
>           // function 2
>           float h3 = t * t * t - 2 * t * t + t; // calculate basis
>           // function 3
>           float h4 = t * t * t - t * t; // calculate basis function 4
>
>           Vector3 point = new Vector3(controlPoints.get(i)).mul(h1);
>           point.add(controlPoints.get(i + 1).tmp().mul(h2));
>           point.add(T1.tmp().mul(h3));
>           point.add(T2.tmp().mul(h4));
>           points.add(point);
>           t += increment;             }       }
>
>   if (controlPoints.size() >= 4)
> ```
>
> points.add(controlPoints.get(controlPoints.size() - 2));
>
> ```
>   return points;  }
> ```
>
> /** Returns a path, between every two control points numPoints are
>   generated and the control points themselves are added too.     * The
>   first and the last controlpoint are omitted. if there's less than 4
>   controlpoints an empty path is returned.   *       * @param points the
>   array of Vector3 instances to store the path in    * @param numPoints
>   number of points returned for a segment */    public void getPath
>   (Vector3[] points, int numPoints) {       int idx = 0;        if
>   (controlPoints.size() < 4) return;
>
> ```
>   for (int i = 1; i <= controlPoints.size() - 3; i++) {
>       points[idx++].set(controlPoints.get(i));            float increment = 1.0f
> ```
>
> / (numPoints + 1);            float t = increment;
>
> ```
>       T1.set(controlPoints.get(i + 1)).sub(controlPoints.get(i -
> ```
>
> 1)).mul(0.5f);            T2.set(controlPoints.get(i +
>   2)).sub(controlPoints.get(i)).mul(0.5f);
>
> ```
>       for (int j = 0; j < numPoints; j++) {
>           float h1 = 2 * t * t * t - 3 * t * t + 1; // calculate basis
>           // function 1
>           float h2 = -2 * t * t * t + 3 * t * t; // calculate basis
>           // function 2
>           float h3 = t * t * t - 2 * t * t + t; // calculate basis
>           // function 3
>           float h4 = t * t * t - t * t; // calculate basis function 4
>
>           Vector3 point = points[idx++].set(controlPoints.get(i)).mul(h1);
>           point.add(controlPoints.get(i + 1).tmp().mul(h2));
>           point.add(T1.tmp().mul(h3));
>           point.add(T2.tmp().mul(h4));
>           t += increment;             }       }
>
>   points[idx].set(controlPoints.get(controlPoints.size() - 2));   }
> ```
>
> /** Returns all tangents for the points in a path. Same semantics as
>   getPath.   *       * @param numPoints number of points returned for a
>   segment    * @return the tangents of the points in the path */    public
>   List getTangents (int numPoints) {       ArrayList
>   tangents = new ArrayList();
>
> ```
>   if (controlPoints.size() < 4) return tangents;
>
>   Vector3 T1 = new Vector3();         Vector3 T2 = new Vector3();
>
>   for (int i = 1; i <= controlPoints.size() - 3; i++) {           float
> ```
>
> increment = 1.0f / (numPoints + 1);           float t = increment;
>
> ```
>       T1.set(controlPoints.get(i + 1)).sub(controlPoints.get(i -
> ```
>
> 1)).mul(0.5f);            T2.set(controlPoints.get(i +
>   2)).sub(controlPoints.get(i)).mul(0.5f);
>
> ```
>       tangents.add(new Vector3(T1).nor());
>
>       for (int j = 0; j < numPoints; j++) {
>           float h1 = 6 * t * t - 6 * t; // calculate basis function 1
>           float h2 = -6 * t * t + 6 * t; // calculate basis function 2
>           float h3 = 3 * t * t - 4 * t + 1; // calculate basis function 3
>           float h4 = 3 * t * t - 2 * t; // calculate basis function 4
>
>           Vector3 point = new Vector3(controlPoints.get(i)).mul(h1);
>           point.add(controlPoints.get(i + 1).tmp().mul(h2));
>           point.add(T1.tmp().mul(h3));
>           point.add(T2.tmp().mul(h4));
>           tangents.add(point.nor());
>           t += increment;             }       }
>
>   if (controlPoints.size() >= 4)
>       tangents.add(T1.set(controlPoints.get(controlPoints.size() -
> ```
>
> 1)).sub(controlPoints.get(controlPoints.size() - 3))
>                 .mul(0.5f).cpy().nor());
>
> ```
>   return tangents;    }
> ```
>
> /** Returns all tangent's normals in 2D space for the points in a
>   path. The controlpoints have to lie in the x/y plane for this      * to
>   work. Same semantics as getPath.   *       * @param numPoints number of
>   points returned for a segment      * @return the tangents of the points
>   in the path */    public List getTangentNormals2D (int
>   numPoints) {      ArrayList tangents = new ArrayList();
>
> ```
>   if (controlPoints.size() < 4) return tangents;
>
>   Vector3 T1 = new Vector3();         Vector3 T2 = new Vector3();
>
>   for (int i = 1; i <= controlPoints.size() - 3; i++) {           float
> ```
>
> increment = 1.0f / (numPoints + 1);           float t = increment;
>
> ```
>       T1.set(controlPoints.get(i + 1)).sub(controlPoints.get(i -
> ```
>
> 1)).mul(0.5f);            T2.set(controlPoints.get(i +
>   2)).sub(controlPoints.get(i)).mul(0.5f);
>
> ```
>       Vector3 normal = new Vector3(T1).nor();             float x = normal.x;
>       normal.x = normal.y;            normal.y = -x;          tangents.add(normal);
>
>       for (int j = 0; j < numPoints; j++) {
>           float h1 = 6 * t * t - 6 * t; // calculate basis function 1
>           float h2 = -6 * t * t + 6 * t; // calculate basis function 2
>           float h3 = 3 * t * t - 4 * t + 1; // calculate basis function 3
>           float h4 = 3 * t * t - 2 * t; // calculate basis function 4
>
>           Vector3 point = new Vector3(controlPoints.get(i)).mul(h1);
>           point.add(controlPoints.get(i + 1).tmp().mul(h2));
>           point.add(T1.tmp().mul(h3));
>           point.add(T2.tmp().mul(h4));
>           point.nor();
>           x = point.x;
>           point.x = point.y;
>           point.y = -x;
>           tangents.add(point);
>           t += increment;             }       }
>
>   return tangents;    }
> ```
>
> /** Returns the tangent's normals using the tangent and provided up
>   vector doing a cross product.      *       * @param numPoints number of
>   points per segment     * @param up up vector   * @return a list of
>   tangent normals */    public List getTangentNormals (int
>   numPoints, Vector3 up) {      List tangents =
>   getTangents(numPoints);       ArrayList normals = new
>   ArrayList();
>
> ```
>   for (Vector3 tangent : tangents)            normals.add(new
> ```
>
> Vector3(tangent).crs(up).nor());
>
> ```
>   return normals;     }
> ```
>
> public List getTangentNormals (int numPoints, List
>   up) {         List tangents = getTangents(numPoints);
>         ArrayList normals = new ArrayList();
>
> ```
>   int i = 0;      for (Vector3 tangent : tangents)            normals.add(new
> ```
>
> Vector3(tangent).crs(up.get(i++)).nor());
>
> ```
>   return normals;     } }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work fine according to the [**api**](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/CatmullRomSpline.html) and the [**source**](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/CatmullRomSpline.java).

The class IS generic. You must be using some old version of the class.
Update to the latest version and the error should be solved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I recently installed everything, when i open the definition (in my post) it does look different then here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/CatmullRomSpline.java

Comment: Try manually replacing gdx.jar in your project. And make sure that there is only one copy of it in your entire project structure.

Comment: Tried that from version 1.1.0 without result. I create my projects using the setup UI, just created a new project with a updated LibGDX library without results. When i import com.badlogic.gdx.math.CatmullRomSpline; it seems to point to a different class, the one in my post. I import automaticly by hovering over the unrecognized class and choose import from badlogic.

Comment: I did not have the right version indeed. It took me ages to setup a working environment for eclipse/LibGDX/Android and finally got it working not realizing i was using an old version (LibGDX just did not update properly. Now i have been fiddling with a manual install for hours and finally have it working properly with the latest version. Why do they make this so hard? I got errors all the time installing updates for Eclipse and getting Gradle to work.